# Can string value in Python 3.8 short-handed f-string be without quotes?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> long_variable_name = 'foo'
>>> f'long_variable_name={long_variable_name}'
'long_variable_name=foo'
>>> f'{long_variable_name=}'
"long_variable_name='foo'"
```

Is it possible to have the second short-handed expression `f'{long_variable_name=}'` produce the same output as the first expression? I.e. without the quotes for the string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `{var=}` syntax defaults to calling an object's
`__repr__`, so you can explicitly declare it call an object's `__str__`, eg:

```
long_variable_name = 'foo'
f'{long_variable_name=!s}'
```

Gives you:

```
'long_variable_name=foo'
```

Comment: I think using the conversion field `f'{long_variable_name=!s}'` might be better than a format specifier. When I tried this with the variable being a dummy class with `__str__` and `__repr__` defined, using `f'{long_variable_name=:s}'` threw an error `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Test.__format__`. Unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: @shriakhilc you're absolutely correct... I was playing with it and meant to paste the line with `!s` from my editor - thanks for pointing it out *slaps self on the wrist* - corrected now - thank you.